# TestDisk has messed up my disk’s partition table and now system won’t boot up

Tags: data-recovery, disk-utility

So, my options are very limited, I have a system image but
want to use it as very last resort , as I don’t want to lose
my files in the partition D of the disk, which is 831Gb.

I am running a full disk check using the system diagnostics 
(from the BIOS?) but am appalled how long it will take, 3.5 hours .

The question I have is, could this full disk check repair the damage that DiskTest has done, or is its purpose something
else entirely?

Comment: So, a day later, you could add your further investigative results to your question...

Comment: It’s actually TestDisk, I keep confusing it, even the name of this software is lousy. I had C and D, after trying to recover a partition with TD C and D were lost (got unallocated) and recovered partition became C, screwing my OS.